# How to change text indicator color in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, colors, themes

[image]

I want to change the part that's Blue in color

Note
`selectionColor: Colors.grey` Only works for the highlighted part and not the cursor.

None of the below work

```
                textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
                  selectionColor: Colors.grey,
                  cursorColor: Colors.grey,
                  selectionHandleColor: Colors.grey,
                ),
                selectedRowColor: Colors.grey,
                primaryColor: Colors.grey,
                primaryColorDark: Colors.grey,
                primaryColorLight: Colors.grey,
                splashColor:Colors.grey,
                shadowColor: Colors.grey,
                accentColor: Colors.grey,
                focusColor: Colors.grey,
                hoverColor: Colors.grey,
                indicatorColor: Colors.grey,
                highlightColor: Colors.grey,
              ),
```

`cursorColor: Main.sThemeBackgroundColor` only works on the cursor when the text isn't selected

I have been breaking my head over this for the past 3 hours and there seems to be nothing on the internet. Any idea how to change this?

Comment: It works on mine. 

Instead of `hot reload`, `stop` it and restart.

If it doesn't work then try `flutter clean` and remove the app from phone or emulator/simulator then retry.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color of cursor indicator than use this attribute in your theme

```
ThemeData(
        textSelectionHandleColor: Colors.green
      )
```

[image]

If you want to change the cursor color simple use this attribute

```
ThemeData(
        cursorColor: Colors.black
      )
```

[image]

Comment: I want to change the color of the handler (the green part).
textSelectionTheme is depreciated and replaced with textSelectionTheme. However, I've used that and am not able to change the color. Could you please look into this?

Comment: try this attribute textSelectionHandleColor: Colors.green already written above, you can change it to some other color.